# Modifying Github repo that I am forked from

Tags: git, version-control, github, git-fork

I set up my fork on our corporate repo but I accidentally forked from another user's fork. While it works ok I would like to change it to be forked form the base repo like it should be. I have made several commits and pull requests already so I would prefer not to lose my work. Does anyone know hoe to modify what upstream repo I am forked from without losing my work?

Comment: You'll need to clarify a bit more about what exactly you want, and what your company set up is.  From what you describe, it sounds like your company has a central canonical repository (let's call it `upstream`), and you want to make your own private fork of it (let's call it `origin`), but you forked from a coworker's private fork instead?  You can change the url of your local repo on your computer using @oao's answer, but that won't change what your remote repo is forked from...your coworker's fork of `upstream`.

Comment: Can you store your commits as diffs, then just apply then step-by-step   to the proper repo.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want?
 https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url

The other obvious solution is to create a patch with your modifications and to apply it on a new repository.

Comment: The link you gave shows how to change the url for a remote repo in a **local repo**, but not how to change what remote repo a fork is forked from.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly.

in your repo you forked from (that's what you work on)

```
git remote add temp REPO-URL
```

and fetch it

```
git fetch temp
```

then in your repo, you have two remotes, `origin` and `temp`.
if you want to merge some commit in `temp` info `origin`, you can merge `temp/master` into `master`(it will be `origin/master`) or cherry-pick from `temp/master`

Answer (score 0):

If your local repo on your computer contains all the commits of your private remote fork, then you should be able to delete the private remote fork, make a new fork of the right upstream repo, then just push all of your local changes to the new private fork.

I would like to point out, however, that if you have any pull requests/issues made to your private remote fork, then you'll probably lose the comments for those when you delete it.  Any pull requests you already merged into your private fork (and fetched into your local repo) you'll be able to keep, though.

As for pull requests to make to your upstream repo, as long as those were merged into the upstream repo, you shouldn't have to worry about losing those.